# NodeJS/express 4 : Can't set headers after they are sent while writing cookie

Tags: node.js, cookies, express

I'm setting up a module to grant authentification by checking cookies. 
This module is called on each routes and if there is no authentificated session it will compare the cookies with the database and grant session.
After each successful compare, the module updates both database and cookie informations and that's where I get the error "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent."

So basicly I have my route "Index" :

```
var check_auth = require('./middleware/check_auth');
module.exports = function(app){

    app.get('/', check_auth, function(req, res){
        if(req.session.userid){
            res.render('index', { title: 'AUTH'});  
        }else{
            res.render('index', { title: 'NOT AUTH'});
        }
    });
};
```

and now my module check_auth :

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '****',
    database: 'nodejs'  
});

function check_auth(req, res, next){
    if(!req.session.userid){
        var cookie_auth = req.signedCookies.auth;
        var cookie_db_id = req.signedCookies.db_id;
        if(cookie_auth && cookie_db_id){
            pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
                var db_id = false;
                query = conn.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', [cookie_db_id]);
                query.on('error', function(err){
                    throw err;
                });
                query.on('result', function(row){
                    db_id = row.id;
                    db_cookie = row.cookie;
                    db_username = row.username;
                });
                query.on('end', function(result){
                    if(db_id && cookie_auth == db_cookie){
                        console.log("OK");
                        req.session.username = db_username;
                        req.session.userid = db_id;
                        var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
                        var crypt = crypto.randomBytes(64).toString();
                        var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(crypt, salt);                    
                        res.cookie('auth', hash, { expires: new Date(Date.now() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)), signed: true, httpOnly: true, secure: true });                          
                        res.cookie('db_id', db_id, { expires: new Date(Date.now() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)), signed: true, httpOnly: true, secure: true });
                        pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {                        
                            conn.query('UPDATE users SET cookie = (?) WHERE id = ?', [hash, db_id], function(err, info){
                                if(err) throw err;
                            });
                        });
                        conn.release();                             
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
    next();
}

module.exports = check_auth;
```

The error appears at the line :

```
res.cookie('auth', hash, { expires: new Date(Date.now() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)), signed: true, httpOnly: true, secure: true });                          
res.cookie('db_id', db_id, { expires: new Date(Date.now() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)), signed: true, httpOnly: true, secure: true });
```

Is this error coming because I'm writing my cookie into an asynchronous function from mysql or is it something to do with the module/routes ? 
Anyway, any solution are welcome.

Comment: Due to the asynchronous nature, `next` will most likely be called immediately. Move your callback inside your `end` handler.

Comment: Thanks!! Works fine! You can add as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: Also do not throw errors in callbacks on your app. Use the pass by error way of node.js/express by doing `return next(err);`.

Comment: @AlexandruB Ok I will. Guess it shows the error on express rendering, right ?

Comment: If you want the error to be done in the rendering you must add your own special logic, it's not automatic. Instead, [Express offers a default error handler](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling) that you add on the `app` itself as the last callback with four arguments. Something like : `app.use(function (err, res, req, next) { ...logic... });`. In your logic you can render depending on the err. I suggest to make your own Error class that uses JavaScript Error object underneath but with more data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the asynchronous nature, `next` will most likely be called immediately. Move your callback inside your `end` handler.

```
function check_auth(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.session.userid) {
        var cookie_auth = req.signedCookies.auth;
        var cookie_db_id = req.signedCookies.db_id;
        if (cookie_auth && cookie_db_id) {
            pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
                if(err) return next(err);
                var db_id = false;
                query = conn.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', [cookie_db_id]);
                query.on('error', function(err) {
                    return next(err);
                });
                query.on('result', function(row) {
                    db_id = row.id;
                    db_cookie = row.cookie;
                    db_username = row.username;
                });
                query.on('end', function(result) {
                    if (db_id && cookie_auth == db_cookie) {
                        console.log("OK");
                        req.session.username = db_username;
                        req.session.userid = db_id;
                        var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
                        var crypt = crypto.randomBytes(64).toString();
                        var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(crypt, salt);
                        res.cookie('auth', cookie_auth, {
                            expires: new Date(Date.now() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)),
                            signed: true,
                            httpOnly: true,
                            secure: true
                        });
                        res.cookie('db_id', db_id, {
                            expires: new Date(Date.now() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)),
                            signed: true,
                            httpOnly: true,
                            secure: true
                        });
                        pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
                            conn.query('UPDATE users SET cookie = (?) WHERE id = ?', [hash, db_id], function(err, info) {
                                if (err) throw err;
                            });
                        });
                        conn.release();
                    }
                    return next();
                });
            });
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey sorry, it worked first time I moved the next but now that I cleared all session/cookie of my browser it's like it waits for the next statement which is never coming. Even if I have the cookie but no session

Comment: Edited it, try moving it outside the if statement. You'll also most likely need more than one if you're depending on multiple operations.

Comment: Yes I had also a next statement in the first `if` (sry hadnt mention that in my comment). Anyway, i got it. Had to add the `next()` in all `if` statement :) Ty

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct about the asynchronous nature of the problem. A simple workaround would be to call the rendering functionality at the end of your query:

```
function check_auth(req, res, next){
if(!req.session.userid){
    var cookie_auth = req.signedCookies.auth;
    var cookie_db_id = req.signedCookies.db_id;
    if(cookie_auth && cookie_db_id){
        pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
            var db_id = false;
            query = conn.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', [cookie_db_id]);
            query.on('error', function(err){
                throw err;
            });
            query.on('result', function(row){
                db_id = row.id;
                db_cookie = row.cookie;
                db_username = row.username;
            });
            query.on('end', function(result){
                if(db_id && cookie_auth == db_cookie){
                    console.log("OK");
                    req.session.username = db_username;
                    req.session.userid = db_id;
                    var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
                    var crypt = crypto.randomBytes(64).toString();
                    var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(crypt, salt);                    
                    res.cookie('auth', cookie_auth, { expires: new Date(Date.now() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)), signed: true, httpOnly: true, secure: true });                           
                    res.cookie('db_id', db_id, { expires: new Date(Date.now() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)), signed: true, httpOnly: true, secure: true });
                    pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {                        
                        conn.query('UPDATE users SET cookie = (?) WHERE id = ?', [hash, db_id], function(err, info){
                            if(err) throw err;
                        });
                    });
                    conn.release();
                    if(req.session.userid){
                        res.render('index', { title: 'AUTH'});  
                    }else{
                        res.render('index', { title: 'NOT AUTH'});
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
next();}`
```

Comment: It's bad practice to do all logic in one function especially when Node.js allows for smart middleware structure and code reuse.

Comment: @AlexandruB Agree, that's the main purpose of why I use a module with routes.